# Matplotlib shows <ErrorbarContainer object of 3 artists> in x axes legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, errorbar

I'm trying to create an errorbar graph showing some data points and their standard deviation. I was able to create exactly what I wanted, the only problem is that **<ErrorbarContainer object of 3 artists>** is showing up in my legend.

[Graph showing <ErrorbarContainer object of 3 artists> instead of nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kplGS.png)
(The data is replicated 3 times because I still haven't finished collecting it)

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

dfs_busca_div = [
    pd.read_csv(r'./out/busca_hash_aberto_divisao.csv', usecols=[3]),
    pd.read_csv(r'./out/busca_hash_aberto_divisao.csv', usecols=[3]),
    pd.read_csv(r'./out/busca_hash_aberto_divisao.csv', usecols=[3])]

dfs_busca_mul = [
    pd.read_csv(r'./out/busca_hash_aberto_multiplicacao.csv', usecols=[3]),
    pd.read_csv(r'./out/busca_hash_aberto_multiplicacao.csv', usecols=[3]),
    pd.read_csv(r'./out/busca_hash_aberto_multiplicacao.csv', usecols=[3])]

dfs_busca_pri = [
    pd.read_csv(r'./out/busca_hash_aberto_primos.csv', usecols=[3]),
    pd.read_csv(r'./out/busca_hash_aberto_primos.csv', usecols=[3]),
    pd.read_csv(r'./out/busca_hash_aberto_primos.csv', usecols=[3])]


df_types = [
    'Progressive Overflow',
    'Duplo',
    'Aberto'
]

df_names = [
    'Divisão',
    'Multiplicação',
    'Primo'
]

def med_dsvp(dfs, key):
    medias_busca = np.array([])
    dsvp_busca = np.array([])
    for df in dfs:
        media = df[key].mean()
        medias_busca = np.append(medias_busca, media)

        desv_pad = df[key].std()
        dsvp_busca = np.append(dsvp_busca, desv_pad)

    return medias_busca, dsvp_busca

medias_busca_div, dsvp_busca_div = med_dsvp(dfs_busca_div, 'TempoBusca')
medias_busca_mul, dsvp_busca_mul = med_dsvp(dfs_busca_mul, 'TempoBusca')
medias_busca_pri, dsvp_busca_pri = med_dsvp(dfs_busca_pri, 'TempoBusca')

x = np.arange(len(df_types))
width = 0.3
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.errorbar(x - width/2, medias_busca_div, dsvp_busca_div, fmt = 'o', capsize=3, label='Divisão')
rects2 = ax.errorbar(x, medias_busca_mul, dsvp_busca_mul, fmt = 'o', capsize=3, label='Multiplicação')
rects3 = ax.errorbar(x + width/2, medias_busca_pri, dsvp_busca_pri, fmt = 'o', capsize=3, label='Primo')

# Add some text for labels, title and custom x-axis tick labels, etc.
ax.set_ylabel('Tempo(s)')
ax.set_title('Tempo de busca hash')
ax.set_xticks(x);ax.set_xticklabels(df_types, minor=False)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0.000, 0.250, 0.010))
plt.grid(which='major', axis='y')
ax.legend()

ax.set_xlabel(rects1)
ax.set_xlabel(rects2)
ax.set_xlabel(rects3)

fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

What can I do in order to stop this weird legend from showing up?

Comment: You are setting `rects1` (and 2 and 3) as the x axis label. They are the return values of the errorbar function. What are you trying to label the x axis with?

Comment: Rect 1 should label 'Divisão'
Rect 2 should label 'Multiplicação'
Rect 3 should label 'Primo'

I'm following this matplotlib tutorial: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html

Comment: Just tested here, removing all ''ax.set_xlabel(rects)" fixes my problems.

Thank you David!